# I want to make a container under app bar which works like a secondary App Bar where I can put my back icon button and title in the center in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-layout

I have tried everything. But I can't find a permanent solution How to put the title in the center while my back icon button on the left side. I want to use this secondary app bar on every screen of my app.
Please check the image below for a better understanding.

[This is the problem that I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv35W.png)

Answer (score 0):

Take a ListView Widget at body of Scaffold and in its children put first widget as a ListTile that comes under AppBar. So that there will be a leading icon and title in center. After that take a Column and add your needed widgets for every page.